# How to update system app in android dynamically

Tags: android

I have my application as system app. Now I want to update that app by coding. After updating this app, in phone settings it is showing "Uninstall" option which I dont want. So please tell me how I can update my app as system app.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot uninstall system apps. But the Uninstall button will still be visible for system apps that have updates installed. Pressing Uninstall will remove the updates.

If you do not want this, then you should update the ROM with your new version, and flash the ROM.